# HttpWebRequest Authentication

Tags: c#, webclient

we have http post method in class mention below

```
public static class Http
    {
        public static byte[] Post(string uri, NameValueCollection pairs)
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                response = client.UploadValues(uri, pairs);
            }
        return response;
        }
    }
```

we are trying to login but not able to login,
please see the post method and its parameter mention below.

```
var response = Http.Post("https://test.com/login.shtml", new     NameValueCollection() {
    { "accountname", "XXXX" },
    { "username", "XXXX" },
    { "password", "XXXX" },
});
```

Comment: Do you know how the receiving end process the data?

Comment: It is not usual to pass auth parameters via post, they are normal passed in an authentication header. See the example in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Lukos I have compare request in fiddler the only difference is it has only one additional parameter i.e. formHash it generate for each request automatically and that we need to send with request.